# Cannot launch Rails application. (qrencoder)

Tags: rubygems

I need to work on an existing project, but when I try to launch the server `rails s` it gave me the following error:

> https://github.com/pjaspers/mina.git (at
>   pj-write-sha-to-revision-file@5826023) is not yet checked out. Run
>   `bundle install` first.

So I ran `bundle install` and after a while it said:

```
Installing qrencoder 1.4.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/qrencoder-1.4.1/ext/qrencoder_ext
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160404-20756-46gi3z.rb extconf.rb
checking for qrencode.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-qrencoder-dir
        --without-qrencoder-dir
        --with-qrencoder-include
        --without-qrencoder-include=${qrencoder-dir}/include
        --with-qrencoder-lib
        --without-qrencoder-lib=${qrencoder-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/qrencoder-1.4.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/qrencoder-1.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/qrencoder-1.4.1/gem_make.out
Installing coffee-script 2.2.0
Installing rdoc 3.12.2
Installing uglifier 2.4.0
Installing less 2.4.0
Installing thin 1.6.1 with native extensions
Installing faraday 0.9.2
Installing rb-inotify 0.9.3
Installing foreman 0.63.0
Installing zeus 0.13.3 with native extensions
Installing pry 0.9.12.6
Installing mocha 1.0.0
Using mina 0.3.1 from https://github.com/pjaspers/mina.git (at pj-write-sha-to-revision-file@5826023)
Installing prawn 1.1.0
Installing remote_syslog_logger 1.0.3
Installing spreadsheet 0.9.7
Installing activemodel 3.2.13
Installing factory_girl 4.2.0
Installing whenever 0.8.2
Installing mail 2.5.4
Installing akami 1.2.1
Installing wasabi 2.5.1
Installing celluloid-io 0.15.0
An error occurred while installing qrencoder (1.4.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install qrencoder -v '1.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I ran `gem install qrencoder -v '1.4.1'` and got the following message

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing qrencoder:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/qrencoder-1.4.1/ext/qrencoder_ext
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160404-15392-b8moz7.rb extconf.rb
checking for qrencode.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-qrencoder-dir
        --without-qrencoder-dir
        --with-qrencoder-include
        --without-qrencoder-include=${qrencoder-dir}/include
        --with-qrencoder-lib
        --without-qrencoder-lib=${qrencoder-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/qrencoder-1.4.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/qrencoder-1.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/qrencoder-1.4.1/gem_make.out
```

And then the logs gave me the following:

```
have_header: checking for qrencode.h... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest.exe -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat conftest.c  -L. -LC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib -L.      -lmsvcrt-ruby220  -lshell32 -lws2_32 -liphlpapi -limagehlp -lshlwapi  "
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: int main(int argc, char **argv)
6: {
7:   return 0;
8: }
/* end */

"gcc -E -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/i386-mingw32 -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0/ruby/backward -IC:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/include/ruby-2.2.0 -I. -DFD_SETSIZE=2048 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -D__MINGW_USE_VC2005_COMPAT -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64   -O3 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-fast-math -g -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wunused-variable -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat  conftest.c -o conftest.i"
conftest.c:5:22: fatal error: qrencode.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <winsock2.h>
4: #include <windows.h>
5: #include <qrencode.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

I honestly don't know how to continue and/or how to install this gem/dependency, any advise?

### **Update 1**

tried the following as well:

1. downloaded the qrencoder.gem file and ran `gem install --local C:\Users\Edward\Downloads\qrencoder-1.4.1.gem`
2. downloaded the qrencoder source from github and ran `gem install qrencoder -- -- with-qrencoder-dir=C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\qrencoder-1.4.1\libqrencode-master`

but keep getting the same errors: .h file not found

### **Update 2**

none of the following worked:

```
gem install qrencoder -- --with-qrencoder-lib=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32

gem install qrencoder -- --with-qrencoder-include=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32

gem install qrencoder -- --with-qrencoder-dir=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32
```

but the following fixed the `checking for qrencode.h... no` issue but gave the following: `checking for QRinput_new() in -lqrencode... no`

```
gem install qrencoder -- --with-qrencoder-dir=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32 --with-qrencoder-lib=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32 --with-qrencoder-include=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32
```

Comment: if you remove that gem and run bundle, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

According to qrencode doc (http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.html.en) : If you are trying to compile this library on MS-Windows, cygwin or some kinds of UNIX-like environments is required.

You should at least use cygwin, best option would be to run your rails environnement in a Linux VM.

Comment: I don't know which commands to run on cygwin :s basic Unix commands work but when I try this `sudo apt-get install qrencode libqrencode-dev` it says `sudo command not found`

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow (I'm on OS X) install/have `libqrencode` on your windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the readme for the gem, it mentions that you need a library.
A library mentions that there's a Windows version. Try installing it and report back with the results

https://code.google.com/archive/p/qrencode-win32/wikis/Downloads.wiki

I don't have a windows computer to check it but probably the installer will have some info included.

As a general note it will help you a lot if you learn to read and understand exceptions you may encounter while installing gems.

In this example you can find line `checking for qrencode.h... no` which means that compiler was looking for `qrencode.h` header file but didn't find it. Then you can go back looking for a requirements section on the gem page and find out information I mentioned above.

Comment: I'm trying to install in on my Windows machine, but following this manual: https://github.com/tux3/qTox/pull/1438/files seems complicated

Comment: @Edward why don't you try the installer I mentioned first?

Comment: already installed it, but it's nothing more than a gui to generate qrcodes, even after I installed this, it can't find the correct lib i.imgur.com/9Z7i3Lr.png

Comment: Ok, can you try downloading source from here https://code.google.com/archive/p/qrencode-win32/source/default/source , putting the files in some known location (eg. `C:\qrencode-win32\` and then trying to install the gem using command `gem install qrencoder -- --with-qrencoder-dir=C:\qrencode-win32\` (also try adding options `--with-qrencoder-lib` and `--with-qrencoder-include` pointing to the same directory

Comment: tried it, all 3 commands gave `checking for qrencode.h... no`

Comment: Can you make sure the file is in that directory (`C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32\qrencode.h`)? And also try all three at once like this `gem install qrencoder -- --with-qrencoder-dir=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32 --with-qrencoder-lib=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32 --with-qrencoder-include=C:\qrencode-win32\qrencode-win32`?

Comment: it is in the directory: https://i.imgur.com/VPDEO7d.png and running them all 3 at once fixes the .h issue but creates a new one: https://i.imgur.com/Qxtpnaz.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108285/discussion-between-michal-szyndel-and-edward).